# Microsoft Dynamics Check if the contact has signed document [docusgin addon]

Tags: dynamics-crm, docusignapi

I was able to create a workflow that sends a document to a contact when a certain condition occurs.

What I want to do, is to automatically "close" the case or opportunity when the contact sign the document and the document "gets back" to the crm.

Is it possible? So far I see the document signed in the "notes" area.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a [Workflow](http://www.powerobjects.com/2013/08/21/send-email-notification-when-adding-note-case-crm/) or plugin to trigger on create of Signed document from Docusign in Notes (Annotation). In there update the status of Case or Opportunity entity.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific. When I create a workflow how exactly do I check that the signed document is created?

Comment: WF will trigger for created Notes, if you have distinguished name or something, check it.